# Inputting text onto a input bar on a website java

Tags: java, html, input, submit

I would like to access my website from a Java program, and log onto my website from inside the code. On "mywebsite.com/login" there are two input boxes, one for the username and one for the password. They are labeled "username" and "password" for their HTML ID's. Is there a way I can submit text to those boxes from inside the code, and then click an "OK" button?

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing some automation test? if so, try this tools

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-expert-selenium-ide/

it can record your hehavior and then export as a junit test case.